# what is the best way to replace thousands of rows of ID names with their corresponding names in python?

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have two datasets. One contains 16169 rows by 5 columns, and I would like to replace one of the columns with their corresponding names. And those corresponding names come from another dataset.

For example:

```
UniProtID    NAME
Q15173     PPP2R5B
P30154     PPP2R1B
P63151     PPP2R2A

DrugBankID  Name    Type        UniProtID   UniProt Name
DB00001 Lepirudin   BiotechDrug P00734  Prothrombin
DB00002 Cetuximab   BiotechDrug P00533  Epidermal growth factor receptor
DB00002 Cetuximab   BiotechDrug O75015  Low affinity immunoglobulin gamma Fc region receptor III-B
```

In this example, I want to replace all the UniProt ID with their corresponding names from the upper dataset example. What would be the best way to do it?

I am really new to programming and python so any suggestion, help is appreciated.

Comment: Are those tab-delimited data sets and are you using modules like `pandas` or you'd prefer pure Python?

Comment: sorry, tab separated, and pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), if some values not match get `NaN`:

```
#change data for match
print (df1)
  UniProtID     NAME
0    O75015  PPP2R5B
1    P00734  PPP2R1B
2    P63151  PPP2R2A

df2['UniProt Name'] = df2['UniProtID'].map(df1.set_index('UniProtID')['NAME'])
print (df2)
  DrugBankID       Name         Type UniProtID UniProt Name
0    DB00001  Lepirudin  BiotechDrug    P00734      PPP2R1B
1    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    P00533          NaN
2    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    O75015      PPP2R5B
```

If instead `NaN`s need original values:

```
df2['UniProt Name'] = df2['UniProtID'].map(df1.set_index('UniProtID')['NAME'])
                                      .fillna(df2['UniProt Name'])
print (df2)
  DrugBankID       Name         Type UniProtID  \
0    DB00001  Lepirudin  BiotechDrug    P00734   
1    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    P00533   
2    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    O75015   

                       UniProt Name  
0                           PPP2R1B  
1  Epidermal growth factor receptor  
2                           PPP2R5B
```

And solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) - need `left` join with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), last remove column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on="UniProtID", how='left')
df['UniProt Name'] = df['NAME'].fillna(df['UniProt Name'])
#alternative
#df['UniProt Name'] = df['NAME'].combine_first(df['UniProt Name'])
df.drop('NAME', axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
  DrugBankID       Name         Type UniProtID  \
0    DB00001  Lepirudin  BiotechDrug    P00734   
1    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    P00533   
2    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    O75015   

                       UniProt Name  
0                           PPP2R1B  
1  Epidermal growth factor receptor  
2                           PPP2R5B
```

---

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on="UniProtID", how='left')
df = df.drop('UniProt Name', axis=1).rename(columns={'NAME':'UniProt Name'})
print (df)
  DrugBankID       Name         Type UniProtID UniProt Name
0    DB00001  Lepirudin  BiotechDrug    P00734      PPP2R1B
1    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    P00533          NaN
2    DB00002  Cetuximab  BiotechDrug    O75015      PPP2R5B
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach to this problem is to perform a SQL-like join on the two tables.

**Note**: This *may* be expensive for larger datasets, I have not experimented with the performance.

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({"UniProtID": ["Q15173", "P30154", "P63151"],
                     "Name": ["PPP2R5B", "PPP2R1B", "PPP2R2A"]})

right = pd.DataFrame({"UniProtID": ["Q15173", "P30154", "P63151"],
                      "UniProt Name": ["Prothrombin", "Epidermal growth factor receptor", "Low affinity immunoglobulin gamma Fc region receptor III-B"],
                      "Type": ["BiotechDrug", "BiotechDrug", "BiotechDrug"],
                      "DrugBankID": ["DB00001", "DB00002", "DB00003"]})

result = pd.merge(left, right, on="UniProtID")
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#overlapping-value-columns

Comment: Thank you! I definitely don't have the budget for it if it's expensive. but I will see :)